# Swift Firebase laggy when updating data in real time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For special purposes, I need to update my Firebase child node every time I enter a letter into my text view, like so:

Enter letter - setValue - enter letter - set value - and so on...

Now, the problem is, that this can become very laggy when typing in things rapidly. Have you an idea how to improve the performance and remove the delays when typing in?

Here's the code I tried:

```
// Upload chat info

DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let encodedText = encoding(string: self.enterTextView.text)
   ref.child("text").child(self.currentUID).updateChildValues(["CurrentText":encodedText!, "timestamp":Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)])
}
```

Comment: Update the Firebase child node outside of the main thread.

Comment: @XavierBauquet The Firebase client already does the interaction with the network off the main thread. So most work once you call `updateChildValues()` happens on another thread. Unless there is lots of work before or after calling `updateChildValues()` there is no way this call is causing choppy UI.

Comment: Updating Firebase with each keypress is probably (generally) a bad idea. It will create a unwanted user experience because that response is dependent on your internet performance (not Firebase). So even if Firebase is wicked fast, if your internet is slow, so will be the UI. Can you update your question with a use case? There are probably better ways to handle user input. Oh - and the code in your question will have no affect on the UI as it's not updating the UI (there's probably more code involved)

Comment: @Jay I'm sorry I would have loved to do that because the idea is genuinely great, but I have signed a confidentiality disclosure.

Comment: lol. That may not apply since it's a very generic situation with generic code and generic data. 'I am reading characters one at a time so I can do a text search in Firebase"

Comment: @Jay Explaining the whole situation in which it is used would mean breach of contract and could cost me a whole lot of money. Be assured: we're not talking simple Firebase search, it's way more complicated.